# Librería algorithm en C

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu

Estoy revisando un código en lenguaje `c` el cual tiene una librería creada por el programador. Dicha librería (`contours`) tiene dentro la siguiente librería: `algorithm`.

El código lo estoy trabajando desde linux con Ubuntu.

El problema es que al momento de compilar el código (el programa principal) me manda error en esa librería, incluso si compilo la librería me manda el mismo error:

```
fatal error: algorithm: no existe el archivo o directorio
```

Dentro del código la librería está declarada como:

```
#include <algorithm>
```

El código corresponde a uno de programación paralela.

No se si tenga que descargar alguna librería o algo así para poder ejecutarlo.
¿Alguien sabe que tengo que hacer para no tener dicho error?

Comment: La librería a la que se hace referencia... ¿la tienes incluida dentro del directorio del programa? Es decir, el compilador necesita conocer las rutas de todos los ficheros que conforman el programa para poder crear el objeto. Asegúrate de que dicha librería `algorithm` está en el directorio de tu proyecto junto al resto de códigos fuente.

Comment: `<algorithm>` no es de C, sino de C++. Puede que esa librería problemática esté hecha en C++, pero *publicando* ciertas funciones usando la convención de C.

Comment: Oh, no sabía. Para compilar programas en C++ con linux, es igual que en C?